# I have issue with retrieving the data received by API call which is GZIP format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

I am having issue with extracting the data from the response received by api call

```
http://open.pkfare.com/apitest/shopping?param="+json_encoded_string
```

where json_encoded_string is base64 encrypted json data, which is done as per the documentation in http://open.pkfare.com/documents/show

As per the documentation the response received will be in gzip format, 
I'm facing issue with retrieving this data to json format. I'd gone through many blogs for the solution but i didn't got the solution and finally end up here

I'm calling this api using ajax call

```
var fbURL = "http://open.pkfare.com/apitest/shoppingparam=" + json_encoded_string;

$.ajax({
    url: fbURL,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (resp) {

        //---i need code for reading the received gzip data here---

    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

Comment: you will get the json data, parse it and use it in the way what you want

Comment: No, the data recieved which can by seen in the network console is «VJ-*Ê/rÎOIU²R2PÒð}ÓÜül ?%±$QÉ*¯4'§¹Xe-  somthing linke this, this one i believe is in gzip format, i'm not quiet sure, i'm new to this

Comment: Possible duplicate of :- [How to use decode jquery script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28321241/4248328)

Comment: @AlivetoDie it is not what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using AJAX post to get this, I will recomond to use server-side language to do it. I think this is the best and only way for it to actually work. 
Post your AJAX request to a server side language then there call the api and do your other coding to parse the data.

Comment: `then there call the api and your other coding to parse the data.` which other coding did you mentioned?

Comment: I mean after getting data from api in the server side, use other functions & coding to get gzip in your shape then return it back to ajax.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help me

Comment: let me share you the steps you need to follow: now you are calling the api url from client side / ajax and you are receiving the data as gzip format. So you want to decode it in client side / javascript which is very complex and possibly not manageable.  So, my suggestion is - send your ajax response to a php file( if you are using php) then inside that php file call the api and there decode the gzip data very easily.